# How can I set DPI info of a JPG in iOS (iPhone/iPad) without changing the image dimensions? (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image, ipad

Is there some way to just set the DPI information of a JPG file without changing its width and height in iOS?

Example: We have a JPG with `2652 x 1850` with `72 dpi`  (IOS Default) and want to create a JPG with the same size `(2652x1850)` with `300 dpi` (just to have a print size more reasonable). Any suggestions will be welcome. Important: we need this in an IPAD/IPHONE application

Comment: We need to do by code...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Data extension in Swift:

```
extension Data {
    mutating func setDpi(_ dpi: Int) {
        let firstPart = UInt8(UInt16(dpi) >> 8)
        let lastPart = UInt8(UInt16(dpi) & 0xff)

        self[13] = 1
        self[14] = firstPart
        self[15] = lastPart
        self[16] = firstPart
        self[17] = lastPart
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
let image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "example")
var imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9)
imageData?.setDpi(300)
```

Comment: This works perfectly if you do not modify the width and/or height values of the image, but does not work at all when you do. Any way it can be updated to support when the dimensions of the image are modified?